# Solr 6 How to change response fields

Tags: solr, lucene

5.1 i need to change filed value of json response how can i do?

Example below

```
{
responseHeader: {
status: 0,
QTime: 2
},
response: {
numFound: 1,
start: 0,
 docs: [
{
Id: "111445",
name: "TEST",
}
]
}
}
```

I need to change response to studentList and docs to students like below

```
  {
responseHeader: {
status: 0,
QTime: 2
},
StudentList: {
numFound: 1,
start: 0,
 Students: [
{
Id: "111445",
name: "TEST",
}
]
}
}
```

Please could you help us to resolve this issue.?

Comment: It's better and easy if you handle it on frontend side.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do it purely on the side of Solr - you need to implement `org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriter`, in a similar to `org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter`, but somehow overriding the field names in the response and provide your own values.

However, I'm 100% sure, that it will be much better option to do your task outside of the Solr (on the side of the service or even on the side of frontend), by just updating response with needed tags.